# Integral $\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin(x)\sin(y)dydx = 4$

Tags: integration

Mathematically, I understand that:

$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin(x)\sin(y)dydx = 4$$

However, a graph of this function seems to indicate that this region lies below the xy plane. Intuitively, it seems like the result of this function should be -4. Can you explain why my intuition is wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must have plotted wrong somehow when you checked. In the given square $[0,\pi]\times[0,\pi]\subseteq \Bbb R^2$ the integrand is never negative.

Comment: You are absolutely correct... Thank for the swift reply

Answer (score 5):

It's obvious that $\sin(x)$ is positive in $[0,\pi]$ so $\sin(x)\sin(y)$ also in  $[0,\pi]\times [0,\pi]$ and you can show that in the graph below.[image]